# OpenLayers - MousePosition show Y coordinates as wrong for ImageStatic with Pixels Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

I have a map with a pixel projection and load a static image in a layer (My image height is 4298).

When I view the coordinates in mouseposition I see that the X is showing correct, but not the Y.

For example: If I move the cursor at the top left corner of my image it shows: 0, 4298 - Which is wrong as it is suppose to show 0, 0. When I move my cursor at the bottom left corner of my image, it shows 0, 0 - Which is also wrong at it is supposed to show 0, 4298. I presume that map click events will also handle the Y wrongly.

How can I correct this?

```
var imgExtent = [0, 0, 6065, 4298];
var imgProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'my-image',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: imgExtent
});
var pageSource = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    projection: imgProjection,
    url: '/url/to/my/image.png',
    imageExtent: imgExtent
});
var pageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: pageSource
});
var imgView = new ol.View({
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(imgExtent),
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 10,
    rotation: 0,
    projection: imgProjection,
    extent: imgExtent
});
var imgMap = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: true
        }
    }).extend([
        new ol.control.FullScreen(),
        new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
        new ol.control.MousePosition({
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(0),
            projection: imgProjection,
            undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
        })
    ]),
    layers: [
        pageLayer
    ],
    renderer: 'canvas',
    target: 'panelEditMainMap-body',
    view: imgView
});
```

Comment: If you want [0, 0] at the top left of the extent use [0, -4298, 6065, 0]

Comment: @Mike In theory this should be achievable also with `ol.proj.Projection` option `axisOrientation: 'esu'`, but it does not work.

Comment: @TomazicM The only tests done in the source code seem to be to distinguish between `en` and `ne`, even defining a projection via proj4 with `+axis=esu` seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Mike Then docs are misleading, since it's clearly stated: `axisOrientation` `The axis orientation as specified in Proj4.`

Comment: @TomazicM I've just checked proj4js and it is not yet supported in a released version although the necessary change has been made https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/pull/344